# recommendation that i got for anti-virus and browser

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop

i got recommendation for most lightly anti-virus and browser for mini laptop

(1.66 atom N280, 2G memory, Windows 7 pro)

the MS Security Essentials anti-virus,

and the Google Chrome for browser

is it really the most lightly anti-virus and browser ?

is there something better ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is of course subjective. But on all the computers that I have been fixing, cleaning up, or re-installing windows on for friends (6 in the last 8 weeks) I have been installing MS Security Essentials. In general I have been really impressed. The integration with the OS, it's ability to catch issues, updating, scanning have all been more than adequate in what I have seen so far. Everyone has been pleased with the results. I'm not sure there is a "Best" in every single category, especially for free, but so far I really like it. And to be honest, I really don't like much from Microsoft and generally use Linux for our family personal computing.

I generally use Firefox, have never had problems with Chrome, it does seem faster, my kids love it and use it primarily.

Comment: They've done a good job on it I agree, +1.

Comment: I was sceptical (MS? Making an *anti*virus?), but I tried it, and it's really very impressive.

Answer (score 3):

For lightweight antivirus, honestly - I think [Eset Nod 32](http://www.eset.com) is actually lighter on resources, but it has gone downhill so much in recent releases, the only one I would recommend is [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/Security_Essentials/).

For Browser, It really depends on your browsing habbits. Google Chrome is a lot faster, but it opens each tab up in another process which typically means more memory being used overall, where as Firefox opens up everything in one process.

I would personally go for [Firefox](http://www.mozilla-europe.org/en/firefox/) with the [Adblock Plus addon](http://adblockplus.org/en/) for browser, and [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/Security_Essentials/) for antivirus.

Comment: If you still choose to go with Google Chrome, you can still get the AdBlock plus extension.

Comment: @Isxek +1 had no idea - need to find it!

Comment: just to make it clear, its name is "AdBlock" on the Chrome extensions list. I have it installed here on Chrome v4.0.302.3 and it works great.